# getIntExtra always returns default current posts not working either

Tags: android, android-intent

When passing data between activity SongDetails and MainActivity getIntExtra always returns default value. Please see code below.

First Activity

```
Log.d("URL", "isIntentDriven = TRUE");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SongDetails.this, MainActivity.class);
                    Log.d("URL", " " + sid);
                    intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();
```

Second Activity

```
private void getSIDIntent() {

    int sid = 0;

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();

    try {
        sid = mIntent.getIntExtra("sid", 0);
        Log.d("URL", "" + sid);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (sid > 0) {
            addSongDownload(sid);
        }
    }

    hideKeyboard();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Tried this also

SongDetails.java putExtra as long Still 0.

```
long sid;
intent.putExtra("sid", sid);
```

Main.java

```
long sid = 0;
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
try {
sid = mIntent.getLongExtra("sid", 0);
```

Comment: In First Activity sid is not an int?

Comment: It is and I'm using the int putExtra I just added that to see but it made no difference.

Comment: what is the value of sid in SongDetails activity?

Comment: The correct "song id". In MainActivity it stays 0

Comment: Do I need to add some Intent Flag when starting not sure?

Comment: why cast it when it is already int?

Comment: To see if it made a difference but it did'nt

Comment: If you remove the `finish();` ?

Comment: Tried that too its becoming nerve racking :(

Comment: MainActivity is android:launchMode="singleTask" so its routing to existing task tried default launch mode still the same.

Comment: that is long and you are casting it to int which will give you nothing and default will be used its either you'll pass it as long not integer

Comment: you just said 114419538 114419538

Comment: I understand you now make it long ill try this,

Comment: SongDetails.java putExtra as long intent.putExtra("sid", sid); long sid; Still 0. Main.java long sid = 0;

  Intent mIntent = getIntent();

  try {
   sid = mIntent.getLongExtra("sid", 0);

Comment: OK I got it but now it only passes if I force close the app in task manager.

Comment: Launchmode single task is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

If `MainActivity` is defined as *singleTop* or *singleTask* then its `getIntent()` method will not point to the new intent you are passing -- it will return the "original" intent. To read the new intent, you actually need to override `onNewIntent()`.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29):

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
>   their package, or if a client used the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag
>   when calling `startActivity(Intent)`. In either case, when the activity
>   is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
>   instance of the activity being started, `onNewIntent()` will be called
>   on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch
>   it.
>
> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use
>   `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.